# Comparing a single field with average of the same field grouped by some other field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that gets the names of the people who are taller from the average height of their gender.

I know how to get the average height of each gender:

`SELECT avg(height), gender from client group by gender`

But I don't know how to compare each person (based on his gender) with this subquery..

This is as far as I could do:

```
SELECT cname 
FROM (SELECT height, cname, gender
        FROM client AS PplHeight
        HAVING (height > (SELECT avg(height) from client group by gender))) AS AboveAvg
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either join:

```
select client.*
from client
join
(
  select gender, avg(height) as avg_height
  from client
  group by gender
) genders on client.gender = genders.gender and client.height > genders.avg_height;
```

Or use a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from client
where height >
(
  select avg(height)
  from client all_clients
  where all_clients.gender = client.gender
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try sub-queries, like this:

```
select *
from client as c inner join
(
    SELECT avg(height) as avgh, gender
    from client
    group by gender
) as t
on c.gender = t.gender and c.height > t.avgh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inner join the subquery on the gender and the height being greater.

```
SELECT c1.cname
       FROM client c1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT c2.gender,
                               avg(c2.height) height
                               FROM client c2
                               GROUP BY c2.gender) x
                       ON x.gender = c1.gender
                          AND x.height > c1.height;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't give the right output. (I have got the answers..)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PplHeight.cname, PplHeight.gender, PplHeight.height
FROM 
  client AS PplHeight,
  (SELECT gender, avg(height) as avg_height from client group by gender) avg_h
WHERE PplHeight.gender = avg_h.gender
  AND PplHeight.height > avg_h.avg_height
```